# android: How can I implement first time tutorial like Go Launcher in my app?

Tags: android, android-layout

Go Launcher have a nice first-time tutorial. it is very similar to Stock ICS first time run. I want to learn how to make the similar tutorial display at the first launch of my app. How can I implement this Transparent view (which interacts with screen objects) in my android app?

[image: First Image]
[image: Second Image]

Answer (score 70, accepted):

I was trying to do [something similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12013334/how-do-you-create-a-transparent-demo-screen-for-an-android-app) using a transparent activity with a viewpager inside it.  I wanted static 'tutorial' images that users could swipe through.

One of the answers to my question mentioned an interesting library (called ShowcaseView).  It seems like it may be a good fit for your requirements as well.

https://github.com/Espiandev/ShowcaseView

Comment: Thank you a lot! I have used the way which you used (transparent activity) but this library is the exact thing I need :)

Comment: Thanks for introduce to library

Comment: Can this library be used for showing guide for drawer icon & menus as well?

Comment: @VivekSinha : No it cannot!

Answer (score 6):

You can either use a FrameLayout or RelativeLayout as root of your Activity/Fragment, and put your "first time" View upon content with a (almost) transparent background, or use another Activity/Fragment themed with a transluscent window. ([like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176922/how-to-create-transparent-activity-in-android))

I'd rather use an Activity/Fragment, but this is up to you!

Answer (score 4):

I wrote little library That contains a simple component for making ​​a app tour. It`s very restricted to my case but maybe could be your case . Single LessonCardView Showed onstartactivity for the first time or on button click Any criticism ,help or advice will be appreciated. thanks https://github.com/dnocode/DnoLib

Answer (score 2):

You can implement a first-time user guide with the Spotlight library by TakuSemba.

It is similar to the one shared above and it is still well-maintained (as of 2021).

https://github.com/TakuSemba/Spotlight