# How to create hint dialog with gesture effect?

Tags: android, android-dialog

I went through many application in which they are providing `dialog` like overlay with some text and `gesture` functionality on it. And I tried to find out if there is any widget in `android framework` for the same but without any success.

I am using **froyo API 8**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a [transparent activity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12192314/1117415) to show your demo screen.

Also check out a library called  [ShowcaseView](https://github.com/Espiandev/ShowcaseView).

Comment: to use Showcaseview we need android version more that 8

Comment: Then stick with the first option.