# Android Educational Welcome Screen - Blue Circle Highlighting with Text

Tags: android, user-interface

How could I add this type of welcome screen to my own application?

Also what is this view called? (See Screenshot)

[image: Welcome to Android - Make yourself at home]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The is a library on git-hub exactly for this purpose you can use:

https://github.com/Espiandev/ShowcaseView

And take a look at this posts if you want to implement some thing like this:

[How do I create a help overlay like you see in a few Android apps and ICS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10216937/how-do-i-create-a-help-overlay-like-you-see-in-a-few-android-apps-and-ics)

[How do you create a transparent demo screen for an Android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12013334/how-do-you-create-a-transparent-demo-screen-for-an-android-app)