# How to draw on a video view in android?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-videoview

I am trying to create and android application that allows the user to draw a circle or other shape on a video feed to highlight a region of interest. Is it possible to draw directly on the video view or even overlay a canvas on top of the video view? I am using Eclipse.

Comment: definitely not possible to draw directly on the VideoView. So your only option is to overlay something over the top of it. Not sure if canvas would work properly or not.

Comment: @FoamyGuy Thanks. Do you have any idea on how to overlay a canvas or something else on top of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could start from creating some bitmap (transparent background) over the video and draw on it? Another idea is to create transparent fragment, it will be probably easier to do and you will have more control over it.

Please search here:
[How do you create a transparent demo screen for an Android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12013334/how-do-you-create-a-transparent-demo-screen-for-an-android-app)