# Screen notifications for user

Tags: java, android

Please, I guess how it is called: an on-screen floating message with small arrow, they used to show to user what button to push when he sees the program for first time. They are usually with text "press this button to..." or "here you can get this.."
How to implement it in android application?

edit: I implemented some buttons on screen, and they say that it is not clear what they are for. I want to show user, when he (she) run the program after update, that this is a button and it is for...

Comment: You want something like this for Android? http://usablica.github.io/intro.js/

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12013334/how-do-you-create-a-transparent-demo-screen-for-an-android-app.

Comment: nope, this is not dublicate, because I want only floating window, without transparent demo screen

Comment: @Vaughan Hilts, yes something like this, but only the part with button, without screen hightlite buttons, etc.

Answer (score 0):

maybe u could make a a whole new UI over ride for floating display or make a
 activity fully transparent with a limited window size 
and over lap it over ur previous activity