# how do you create a transparent demo screen for delphi android

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-xe5, firemonkey-fm3

Can I do this [How do you create a transparent demo screen for an Android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12013334/how-do-you-create-a-transparent-demo-screen-for-an-android-app) with Delphi XE5 on the Android and iOS platforms.

Thanks for your help, pointing me to the right direction

Comment: How can I create this using delphi xe6-8: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12013334/how-do-you-create-a-transparent-demo-screen-for-an-android-app?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do this without any problems. [This is an application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.embarcadero.MarfinElForn&hl=es) (a prototype) is made with Delphi XE5.

If you see the captures, you can see this:

[image: ScreenCapture, whith a semi-transparent panel]

I have used a semi-transparent panel with alignement alCenter (in you case you can align the panel alClient for all screen). You can modify the level of transparency with the Opacy property. In addition, I have used an effect (blur) with the background form (this is not necesary for you).

Regards.

Comment: Question is about semi-transparent main form of the application, no semi-transparent panel. I haven't found the solution yet.

Comment: Maybe it's not correct (it is correct if you can do it in Java) but user need solution, and it's possible in JAVA so he's looking for similar behavior with Delphi

Answer (score 0):

In the AndroidManfestTemplate.xml of your app, add this line

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
```

to the

```
 <application android:persistent="%persistent%"
```

section.