# Android Custom options menu

Tags: android, menu

I want to create custom options menu like that in the picture:

http://postimg.org/image/g594grvoj/

Maybe someone knows tutorial how to achieve something like that? I have already tried from this link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/173121/Android-Menus-My-Way . But problem is that I can`t add menu to menu button.

Comment: Maybe this would help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12013334/how-do-you-create-a-transparent-demo-screen-for-an-android-app