# android app launch instruction slideshow

Tags: android, android-layout, slideshow, launch

Many apps when I launch them for the first time, take me through a slide show. I want to do the same in my app. I have no idea how it's done and how to go about it. Is there a library that does this? What are some ways I can do this? From my question you can see I have no clue how to even start going about it; but you can also see that the question is clear. So thanks for any hint.

Comment: I think same subject is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12013334/how-do-you-create-a-transparent-demo-screen-for-an-android-app.

Answer (score 0):

Create an Activity for the instructions. Check in your MainActivity whether the app is first launched. If so, start the activity.

Answer (score 0):

You have to start a new [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) for this, containing a slideshow with your instructions.
First check if the tutorial has been already launched before, maybe using [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) to save the status.

Comment: So it is truly a slideshow? I call it a slide show, but I didn't know that it actually was. So it is truly a set of pictures that I am running in front of the user? Thanks.

Comment: There are many styles for app tutorials, images slideshow is only one of them, and maybe the most simple to make.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are searchig for something like [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Famlcurran%2FShowcaseView&ei=k9LgVLeaAo7SoASRtILgBg&usg=AFQjCNH_mK0gBxhpjPl1lxYyUf1IvW7R3A&sig2=rQBB13xXfEsmILuyYJxKCw&bvm=bv.85970519,d.cGU&cad=rja) or [this](https://github.com/marvinlabs/android-slideshow-widget) .

And also you can use [ViewPagerIndicator](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ViewPagerIndicator) library.

Some other usful links:

[android-viewflow](https://github.com/pakerfeldt/android-viewflow)

[viewpagerindicator.com](http://viewpagerindicator.com/)