# How to create a transparent demo screen for phonegap android app

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, demo, showcaseview

I want to create a semi-transparent demo screen that is launched only when a user first installs my application. I looked in the internet and I found this [How do you create a transparent demo screen for an Android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12013334/how-do-you-create-a-transparent-demo-screen-for-an-android-app) which is the thing I want to do but not with phonegap

Comment: Just create an div as an overlay and put the elements in it.

Comment: and how to make it appears only the first time the user installs the app?

Comment: Create a flag (variable) e.g. firstRun and save the value in localStorage and check this value on every app start. If the value is e.g. 1 then show the overlay.

Comment: emm, thank you very much. I'll give it a try.