# How to show App instructions in ionic on first startup

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app, demo

I am new to ionic framework. I want to show app instructions like this.

[image]

what api/framework i should use to achieve this.Or if anyone have code samples,code pen help me in learning this.

Comment: i cant post image..please check in that link

Comment: Ionic is just built with angular, so create a div or img tag and put your semi-transparent image in it with a z-index higher than your main content.

Comment: it is not looking good...

Comment: I want to build a similar feature into my app. Therefore i bookmarked an example from Mike Hartington, a developer from the ionic framework. Take a look at his [codepen example](http://codepen.io/mhartington/pen/GgeYaM).

Comment: Hey @Beat, thanks for codepen.. but can you check image i posted(link). I want to implement that type of feature

Comment: What about this [SO Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12013334/how-do-you-create-a-transparent-demo-screen-for-an-android-app)? Seems to be the same

Comment: That is native android @Beat

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you mean a "tour" or "intro" feature you can try to use one of the various AngularJS plugins:

https://github.com/abhikmitra/ng-joyride/

http://code.mendhak.com/angular-intro.js/example/index.html

http://daftmonk.github.io/angular-tour/

https://github.com/benmarch/angular-ui-tour

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-tour

Those ones are for web sites but you can evaluate if they could meet your needs.

Comment: Thanks, ng-joyride is what i wanted..i am going to try now, I will confirm once its done