# Fix Layout changes if device language is Arabic

Tags: android

I have to support both "ltr" and "rtl" in my app.
    I have tested my app on ltr and it works but when i tested my layouts on an arabic phone languague the images and the texts are dispersed

**Issue**

The image and textbox in rtl are inversed.
    I want the textbox and image position are same as in the **"ltr"**

```
My layout.xml:

   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/Grey_50"
    app:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image_news"
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="end"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_news_title"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="start"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/image_news"
                    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                    android:textSize="13sp" />
                <View
                    android:id="@+id/view1"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/image_news"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/recent"
                            android:layout_width="15dp"
                            android:layout_height="15dp"
                            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/ic_recent"
                            android:textAlignment="center" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/txt_timedate"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/recent"
                            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/recent"
                            android:text="20:49"
                            android:textColor="@color/Grey_600"
                            android:textSize="16sp" />
                </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Image showing app screen supporting ltr and rtl.
   [image]

Comment: set layout direction as ltr for the parent layout.

Comment: @Nas wow it works ! but they're saying layout direction is only used in API 17 and higher(current min is 16)

Does this warning message makes fear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set layout direction as **ltr** for the parent layout

Its only support from api level 17. If you want to support for previous api level you have to make separate xml layout file for arabic.

Comment: Thanks but can u send me some documentation or any stuff about making separate xml file for arabic?

Comment: Wow awesome @Nas only one thing if would i want to ask something:
I want when the activity launches..it lauches before it a TRANSPARENT slider saying like : Don't forget to swipe down to get the latest news

Comment: sorry am not clear with your question. is this log text?

Comment: Like the first picture in this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12013334/how-do-you-create-a-transparent-demo-screen-for-an-android-app

Comment: You can find the answer on the same page by scrolling. If you need any more assistance post it as a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your XML code with this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/Grey_50"
    app:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layoutDirection="rtl">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_news"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_news_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/image_news"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/image_news"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:textSize="13sp" />
        <View
            android:id="@+id/view1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/image_news"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/recent"
                android:layout_width="15dp"
                android:layout_height="15dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_recent"
                android:textAlignment="center" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_timedate"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/recent"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/recent"
                android:text="20:49"
                android:textColor="@color/Grey_600"
                android:textSize="16sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Sorry it worked with android:layoutDirection="ltr" not             android:layoutDirection="rtl"

Answer (score 0):

Need to make sure that android:supportsRtl is FALSE in androidManifest

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_original"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="false" />
```