# How to show tips when app loads first time?

Tags: android

i have a app with both side navigation drawer and i was thinking to provide some sort of information such that when the app loads first time, a sort of view should come above the fragment or activity's view like below showing tips such as "Tap here to view navigation drawer".

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11805890/1665507. see the answer to this question.

Answer (score 7):

Check the [ShowcaseView](https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView) library.

Comment: Is there any other library than ShowcaseView ?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a pretty library for that: [ShowCase](https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView)

Comment: Is there any other library than ShowcaseView ?

Answer (score -2):

```
private static final String PREFS_NAME = "prefs";
private static final String IS_FIRST_LAUNCH = "is_first";
```

---

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
        boolean isFirst = settings.getBoolean(IS_FIRST_LAUNCH, true);
        if (isFirst){
            settings.edit().putBoolean(IS_FIRST_LAUNCH, false).commit();
            showTips();
        }
```

at showTips() show dialog/activity/fragment as you want.

Comment: I wasn't asking this. Do read the question again and the answers other people provided

Comment: @RahulGupta I did read/looked at your question and I don't understand why this can't be an answer on your question, hence I don't understand the downvotes. The other answers are recommending a library which I didn't read clearly from your question. If you were not interested in a code sample you should have stated that explictely. I find your question unclear.

Comment: @rene "I don't understand why this can't be an answer on your question, hence I don't understand the downvotes" - This is plain wrong answer, OP clearly shared screenshot what type of view he wants to add in his app and question seems clear to me !