# Add tutorial in the starting of application

Tags: android

I am creating an Android application and i want to add the tutorial at the starting of the screen and it should be displayed only once. I want to know to create such tutorial screens.

I have added screenshot of an application which has implemented similar functionality. [Here is the link to the application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.candl.athena&hl=en)

[image]

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13169404/1777090). You can try [Show case view](https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView)

Answer (score 0):

For tutorial creation it is helpfull to use Fragments.

Please start research [this link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html) for taking survey of fragments.

Answer (score 0):

I think adding a transparent full screen view will be enough.
If you want to make a hole that allows the button below to be pressed, you might be able to do that with controlling touch event.
If you're care about the positions of each guide, I think you can make it by programmatically because you know each guided item and can get absolute position from window or root.
(And if the base layout of all guided items is RelativeLayout, you can just add guide items in it relatively)