# android- How to make educational semi-transparent images when app runs for the first time

Tags: android

I've seen this in some apps , When the user runs the application for the first time, it shows some semi transparent screen shots that points to a certain part and shows some texts under it .

What does it calls ? How can I make some for my application ?

Edit:
this is the image of what i mean :
[image]

thanks

Comment: it is called `walk-through` / `showcase` / `in-app tour`

Comment: that is simply an image which you can program to show at first launch and then don't show it for next time.

Comment: Please check these links. Hope it may help you: 1) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12013334/how-do-you-create-a-transparent-demo-screen-for-an-android-app?rq=1 2) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11805890/android-how-can-i-implement-first-time-tutorial-like-go-launcher-in-my-app?lq=1

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this
[image]

here's the github url: [showcase](https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView)

> EDIT:
>   Then take a look at [this](http://www.christianpeeters.com/android-tutorials/android-tutorial-overlay-with-user-instructions/)

there are also some of library there but i', not sure it's work for you
[lib](https://github.com/DavidBenko/TutorialView/tree/master/Android/TutorialViewSample)
try this and let me know if it work for you.

Comment: @mohamadbagheri hey i just edited my answer take a look.